# iPhone app store individual developer information

Tags: app-store

Is there a way to not publish the app developer's full name in the app store?

Comment: If you could, do you think potential customers would be more likely or less likely to trust the application? I personally don't install applications unless I trust the author of the application or am given enough information to know their reputation is staked on the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Create a company and publish your apps as that company instead of your own name.